# Share a constant value using multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

Consider the networked multiprocessing setup as in http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/24/distributed-computing-in-python-with-multiprocessing/ (That is, one server with two queues shared with many connecting clients on the network).

I would like to extend this example such that the server can share some parameters with all clients. Following the linked code, I extended the `JobQueueManager` (the **server** side) by registering an extra callable (the `get_params` bit):

```
JobQueueManager.register('get_job_q', callable=lambda: job_q)
JobQueueManager.register('get_result_q', callable=lambda: result_q)
JobQueueManager.register('get_params', callable=lambda: ['123'])

manager = JobQueueManager(address=('', port), authkey=authkey)
manager.start()
```

To make this work, I had to change the **client** code as follows

```
job_q       = manager.get_job_q()
result_q    = manager.get_result_q()
params      = manager.get_params()._getvalue()
```

But, why do I need the `_getvalue()` while that is not needed on the queues? Is there a better/proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that you want a `ListProxy`, so that you get seamless access to the normal list `__dunder__` methods like `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, etc.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import ListProxy

JobQueueManager.register('get_params', callable=lambda: ['123'], proxytype=ListProxy)
```

If you don't specify `ListProxy`, you end up only getting access to public methods from the list object (`append`, `extend`, etc.).